# Escaping user inputted data - WordPress Shortcode Attributes

Tags: wordpress, security

Do shortcode attributes in WordPress need escaping if it's user inputted data?

This plugin suggests accepting unsanitised from user input and passing it through via the shortcode.
https://connekthq.com/plugins/ajax-load-more/extensions/relevanssi/

Surely this should be sanitised similar to my example below?

I am I write to think this should be sanitised and is my method the recommended way?

```
$term = (isset($_GET['search'])) ? $_GET['search'] : '';
echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more id="relevanssi" search="'. esc_html($term) .'"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would double-down & both sanitize the url-param using [`sanitize_key`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_key/) and escape it as you've already done, but using [`esc_attr`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) rather than `esc_html`:

```
$term = ( isset($_GET['search'])) ? sanitize_key( $_GET['search'] ) : '';
echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more id="relevanssi" search="'. esc_attr($term) .'"]');
```

Also, it would be preferable to use the `ajax_load_more` function directly rather than do_shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to escape user input data, I would like to suggest using [sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) which is recommended to use for user input field data sanitization. If i am going to rewrite your code sample then it would be like

```
$term = (isset($_GET['search'])) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['search']) : '';
echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more id="relevanssi" search="'. esc_html($term) .'"]');
```